# The intersection of two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question: In the group $S_3$ find the intersection of the subgroups <(1 2 3)> and <(1 2)>.

How do I find the intersection with my groups are permutations?  I know that the $ord_{s_3}$ ((1 2 3)(1 2))=lcm[3,2]=6. Also, how does the order and intersection relate?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply find the subgroups themselves and then see what's in both:

$$\langle(123)\rangle=\{1,(123),(132)\}$$
$$\langle(12)\rangle = \{1,(12)\}$$

The only element in both is the identity, so the intersection is $\{1\}$.

What you said about the order is wrong; if the order of that intersection were $6$ then the intersection would be equal to all of $S_3$ because ord$(S_3)=6$.

There's another way to get this a bit easier as well. The intersection of subgroups $H$ and $K$ will always be a subgroup itself of both $H$ and $K$. Therefore the order of $H\cap K$ must divide the orders of both $H$ and $K$.

Applying to our problem, the order of $\langle (123)\rangle$ is equal to the order of $(123)$, which is $3$, and the order of $\langle(12)\rangle$ is equal to $2$, so the order of the intersection must divide both $2$ and $3$, so it must have order $1$ and just be the identity.

Comment: RE order: Ohhh, is that because they are not disjoint. Because if they're disjoint then you can take the lcm, right?

Comment: @ematth7 Subgroups can't be disjoint; they'll always each have the identity.